# Problem facing using oscommerce with 2checkout payment module

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

[This is a screenshot where did i am stuck.I got this error.I can update catalog payment checkout.php file but same error are occur.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLLzh.png)

Answer (score 0):

looks like an problem with your parameters, the source must look like this :

```
<form action='https://www.yourwebsite.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='sid' value='123' >
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity1' value='1' >
    <input type='hidden' name='product_id1' value='1008' />
    <input type='hidden' name='quantity2' value='1' >
    <input type='hidden' name='product_id2' value='1014' >
    <input name="submit" type='submit' value='Buy from 2CO' >
</form>
```

Note : the variable "sid" is needed to recognize to payment account !